# Build error when using Amazon Device Messaging: class must extend android.app.Service [Instantiatable]

Tags: android, kindle-fire, amazon-device-messaging

I'm integrating **Amazon device messaging** into my app following this [Offical docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/integrate-your-app.html). According to the docs, I have to create a class (MyADMMessageHandler.java) that extends **ADMMessageHandlerJobBase** and declare my class as a Service in AndroidManifest.xml

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".pn.MyADMMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

But when I built my app, I got this error

```
AndroidManifest.xml:153: Error: MyADMMessageHandler must extend android.app.Service [Instantiatable]
  <service android:name=".pn.MyADMMessageHandler"                           

   Explanation for issues of type "Instantiatable":
   Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest
   file (or for custom views, in a layout file) must be "instantiatable" by
   the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have an
   empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a static
   inner class.

1 errors, 0 warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
```

Despite of this error, I still had BUILD SUCCESSFUL.
I decompiled **amazon-device-messaging-1.1.0.jar** to see what's going on, but it just contains stub implementation and **ADMMessageHandlerJobBase** doesn't extends Service or any subclass of Service.

So MyADMMessageHandler class isn't a Service but why do we need to declare it as a Service in AndroidManifest.xml?

Note: In the [sample code](https://amzndevresources.com/adm/sdk/AmazonDeviceMessaging.zip) of Amazon device messaging, it also did the same.

**Update 1**

I've also asked [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/233699/build-error-class-must-extend-androidappservice-in.html), and received the answer:

> If you are following this [1](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/integrate-your-app.html) documentation then you should be fine. The error you see should just be a warning and can be ignored. The declaration in AndroidManifest.xml is a must.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has answered this question.  It's a legitimate issue with `ADMMessageHandlerJobBase`

Comment: I am having the same issue and my ADMMessageJobBase callbacks are not triggering. Can anyone help ?

Comment: @Fahad-Android did you find a solution for the callbacks not triggering?